# Service worker could not subscribe pushManager

Tags: javascript, laravel, web, service-worker, pusher

I am trying to send desktop push notifications to browser and I do it successfully but unable to send when site tab is closed. For this i am using service worker but it could not subscribe the push manager.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(fileSw);
 navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        .then(async function(registration) {
            const appKey = '{!! env('APP_KEY') !!}';
             const convertedVapidKey = convertDataURIToBinary(appKey);
            return registration.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly: true,
                applicationServerKey: convertedVapidKey
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

pushManager returns with a proimise if I can see it correctly here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager

Shouldn't you need to put some logic into a .then() handler? What would you like to happen exectly and where is the code to actually do that action?

Comment: I am receiving pending in promise after pushManager subscription I want to send desktop notification when site is closed.

Comment: @HaiderHussain In the example on the referenced MDN article the onpush() event handler is defined. Which contains the logic of what .should happen on the event. I can't see that section in your code snippet.